# how to solve CORS Origin error from angular

Tags: angular

I have created an angular app, when I do POST, PUT and DELETE methods I am getting this error:

```
 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows 
 reading the remote resource at http://dev-****- 
 app.south****.cloudapp.azure.com/app/users/users/updateuser/21. (Reason: CORS 
 request did not succeed)
```

This is my API call:

```
sercice.ts:

   UpdateUsers(updatedata){
   let user_id = localStorage.getItem("user_id");
   return this.http.put(this.userupdate_url+user_id, updatedata).pipe(map(response=>{
      if(response['Successful']){
        this.router.navigate(['/users']);
      }
     }));
   }
```

how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

- Try white-listing domains to prevent CORS error in those.
- Do proxy configuration in config files.
- Enable CORS in your server.

If you are using for testing purposes, change headers to

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This will allow all origins.

Still didnt work?

Add this link before your request url,

https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Example: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://dev-****- 
 app.south****.cloudapp.azure.com/app/users/users/updateuser/21

Comment: I have enabled CORS in the server

Comment: how to do white-listing domains

Comment: Whitelisting logic differs for each application. Basically you'll have config file where you'll specify domains. Check updated answer